# React component isn't importing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made several React components and have imported them all correctly into a different component, however, one isn't lighting up like the rest of them are in VS Code.

This is my component that I am trying to import to my other component, but it's not working for some reason.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './TrackList.css';
    import Track from '../Track/Track';

    class TrackList extends React.Component {
        render() {
           return (
              <div className="TrackList">
                  {
                      this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                          return <Track track={track}
                                          key={track.id}
                                          onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                                          onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                                          isRemoval={true} />
                      })
                  }
              </div>
          )
     }
   };
    

   export default TrackList;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add details

Comment: wrong path most likely

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages, that section of code just doesn't seem to be importing. When I wrote the import syntax to import my TrackList component to my App file the words aren't all bright and vibrant in VS Code like the other components I've imported into the same App file are.

Comment: you need to provide more context/screenshots, because the code you provided is fine. You should also be using functional components rather than class components, especially for one as simple as this :)